# How to provide ID for ion-floating-menu

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, appium

I want to provide ID attribute for `ion-floating-menu` or `ion-floating-button`. Even though if we provide it as how we use to provide for all other elements, it is not reflecting in `Appium`.

Test Engineers need it for mobile app automation, used technologies to develop mob app: `Javascript`, `angularjs`, `ionic-framework`.

```
<ion-floating-button id="menu_btn" icon="ion-plus" ng-disabled="noConection" ng-click="onCreateCaseDairy()" button-color="#0C8ED8"
icon-color="white">
```

Comment: can you add **ion-floating-button* inside div or any other containter?? if you can do that you can add id there.

Comment: Yes, It is working for ionic-floating-button.                                                                                       But is there any solution for ion-floating-menu.

Comment: can't you add ion-floating-menu inside the container? If you can, do it similar like ion-floating-button

Comment: It is working fine for both flosting-button and as well as menu. Thank you @Suban Dhyako

Comment: you are welcome. Glad that this helped you. :)